# ios 7 drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates: black screen on iPad only

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios7

I've got very weird situation... I'm trying to capture content from scroll view (which `contentSize` exceeds screen bounds three times) by calling `drawViewHierarchyInRect: afterScreenUpdates:` as below:

```
+ (UIImage *) imageFromScrollView: (UIScrollView *) scrollView {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);

    [view drawViewHierarchyInRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, scrollView.contentSize.width, scrollView.contentSize.height)
               afterScreenUpdates: YES];

    UIImage * image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();  

    return image;  
}
```

It works on: iPhone device, iPhone and iPad Simulator, but **doesn't** work on iPad **device**. Have you ever had similar issue? I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Have you tried [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()]; to see if you get any different results? Also, it shouldn't make the image completely black, but another thing is you shouldn't really be using UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(). Instead use UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(). That way it will show up correctly for both retina/non retina devices.

Comment: I've also tried with `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` and with `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext()`. Previously, I used `renderInContext:` method which you mentioned, but I wanted to leverage new methods from iOS 7, which seems to be faster.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
```

NO is important here since it returns a non-opaque image.

Answer (score -1):

This code works for me.

```
UIImage *image = [SnapShotter snapShotEntireScrollingView:self.receiptTableView];


+ (UIImage *)snapShotEntireScrollingView:(UIScrollView *)view
{
    return [self snapShotEntireScrollingView:view withEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
}


+ (UIImage *)snapShotEntireScrollingView:(UIScrollView *)view withEdgeInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)insets
{
    CGRect currentFrame = view.frame;

    CGRect fullFrame = view.frame;
    fullFrame.size.width = MAX(currentFrame.size.width, view.contentSize.width);
    fullFrame.size.height = MAX(currentFrame.size.height, view.contentSize.height);
    view.frame = fullFrame;

    UIImage *image = [self snapShotView:view withEdgeInsets:insets];

    view.frame = currentFrame;
    return image;
}
```

Comment: Your solution is pretty straightforward, but it still doesn't work on my iPad device... Finally, I've decided to capture my screen with `renderInContext:` method. I wanted to use new method for iOS 7, but it wasn't possible. Thanks for your help :)